# Remove esc_html

Tags: php, jquery, html

Is it possible to remove esc_html from the output so any HTML links added to a custom field, link in the HTML output?

```
<a href="https://example.com">example.com</a>
```

Here's is my PHP code:

```
esc_html( get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true) ) );
```

The problem i have is there's no filter added to the PHP so i can't modify the output.

Maybe there's a jQuery solution or something.

When i modify the code in the plugin it works but thats not future proof.

```
 get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true) );
```

Edit: Here's the HTML source
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use wordpress. You should never trust your user by bypassing validation. But there are other options than `esc_html`.

Have a look at [Data Validation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation), more specifically the `wp_kses`family functions.

For example, the `wp_kses()` function accepts three arguments ([full tuto here](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/data-sanitization-and-validation-with-wordpress--wp-25536)):

- `content` – (string) Content to filter through kses
- `allowed_html` – An array where each key is an allowed HTML element and the value is an array of allowed attributes for that element
- `allowed_protocols` – Optional. Allowed protocol in links (for example http, mailto, feed etc.)

`wp_kses()` is thus a very flexible function, allowing you to remove unwanted tags, or just unwanted attributes from tags.

Example:

```
$content = "<em>Click</em> <a title='click for wp.tuts+' href='http://wp.tutsplus.com'>here</a> to visit <strong> wptuts+ </strong>";

echo wp_kses( $content, array(
    'strong' => array(),
    'a' => array('href')
) );

// Prints the HTML "Click <a href='http://wp.tutsplus.com'>here</a> to visit <strong> wptuts+ </strong>":
Click <a href="http://wp.tutsplus.com">here</a> to visit <strong> wptuts+ </strong>
```

*Note*: careful though. As specified in the docs "the kses system can be resource-intensive".

Comment: Thanks but i can't edit the plugins code. I'm not the Developer. I need a solution to allow <a tags so the HTML for the website link works.